# Automatic exporting of SSRS to PowerPoint via URL parameter using Aspose.Slides

Tags: sql-server, powerpoint, reporting-services, aspose

Using Aspose.Slides (a product that allows exporting SSRS to PowerPoint), can I supply a URL parameter that automatically outputs as PPT? Native SSRS allows automatic output of PDF, Excel, etc. via the `rs:Format` parameter, like so:

> http://localhost/ReportServer?/myFolder/myReport&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF

Is there a `rs:Format=` parameter that allows outputting as PowerPoint? I tried `PPT` and `PowerPoint`, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use ASPPT for PPT and ASPPTX for PPTX

Comment: Thanks. I added an answer that lists the PPS and PPSX extensions, too.

Answer (score 0):

Aspose uses the following values in the `rs:Format=` parameter to export automatically via URL:

```
ASPPT     PowerPoint presentation (*.ppt)
ASPPS     PowerPoint slideshow (*.pps)
ASPPTX    PowerPoint 2007+ presentation (*.pptx)
ASPPSX    PowerPoint 2007+ slideshow (*.ppsx)
```

I figured it out by viewing the `value` of each item in the export `select` list using FireBug.